# I can not Auto load data when I select another city

Tags: json, ajax, reactjs

Code get api weather: I can not Auto load data when I select another city.
I want when I choose another city, my data will change.

```
class AppMain extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: 'Ha Noi',
            city:'',
            status:'',
            statusimg:'',
            temp:'',
            wind:'',
            humidity:'',
            time:''
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.getjson = this.getjson.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    }

    getjson() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=8f226d9ba4bb4bb58ef85947171107&q=' + this.state.value,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                this.setState({ city: data.location.name });
                this.setState({ status: data.current.condition.text });
                this.setState({ temp: data.current.temp_c });
                this.setState({ time: data.current.last_updated });
                this.setState({ statusimg: data.current.condition.icon });
                this.setState({ humidity: data.current.humidity });
                this.setState({ wind: data.current.wind_kph });
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.getjson();
    }

    render() {   
        return (
            <div className="main">
                <div className="choose-title">
                    <p>Choose City</p>
                    <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                        <option value="Ha Noi">Hà Nội</option>
                        <option value="Ho Chi Minh">Hồ Chí Minh</option>
                        <option value="Da Nang">Đà Nẵng</option>
                    </select>
                </div>


                <div className="display">
                    <table className="table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Name city:</td>
                                <td id="namecity">{this.state.city}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Update: {this.state.time}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td id="status">{this.state.status}</td>
                                <td id="status-img"><img src={this.state.statusimg} alt=""/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Temp:</td>
                                <td id="temp">{this.state.temp}°C</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Wind:</td>
                                <td id="wind">{this.state.wind} Km/h</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Humidity:</td>
                                <td id="">{this.state.humidity}%</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your component might only mount once; therefore, you only getjson once. You will need to getjson everytime your city is updated; perhaps in handleChange().

Comment: normalized whitespace and semicolons in code, removed 4x duplicate sentence